# How to add a constraint index in yaml Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, yaml

I`ve got two tables described in YAML.

For example :

```
Entities\User:
  type: entity
  table: users
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    username:
      type: string
      length: 64
  oneToMany:
    children:
      targetEntity: UserToUser
      mappedBy: parent
    parents:
     targetEntity: UserToUser
     mappedBy: child

Entities\UserToUser:
  type: entity
  table: user_to_user
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
    child_id:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
  manyToOne:
    parent:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: children
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    child:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: parents
      joinColumn:
        name: child_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

in this case everything generates well but in fact in database in table `user_to_user` there in no unique index for fields: `user_id` and `child_id`.
So there is the possibility to add 2 entries with the same value.

I was trying to add constraints

```
uniqueConstraints:
    child_user_idx:
      columns: child_id,user_id
```

or 2 other ways:

```
id:
    user_id:
      type: integer
    child_id:
      type: integer
```

or

```
  id:
    parent:
      associationKey: true
    child:
      associationKey: true
```

Trying to combine these options but as the result using doctrine console validation, there were errors every time but generated SQL was exactly what I needed.

One of them for example:

The join columns of the association `parent` have to match to ALL identifier columns of the source entity `Entities\UserToUser`, however, `child_id` is missing.

- The join columns of the association `child` have to match to ALL identifier columns of the source entity `Entities\UserToUser`, however, `user_id` is missing.

I do not really understand what I have to add so the validation pass correctly

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with that mapping? you want each user to have a collection of users? and an attribute that is the "parent" user?

Comment: I want to find the solution to add unique index for 2 foreign keys using yaml

Answer (score 3):

While using YAML you can try to use the following notation:

```
Vendor\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: category
    indexes:
        # the name of the index
        category_slug_idx:
            # Columns is an array, specify multiple columns for
            # a compound index
            columns: [ slug ]
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }

    fields:
        name:
            type: string
        slug:
            type: string
```

you can see that you can declare the indexes under the indexes: node

Comment: You appear to have directly copied my answer (from the gist I posted) as a separate answer, hence the downvote

Comment: Why not "post the answer" you didn't answer the question, just posted a link and a random yaml schema that doesn't answers the question "how to add a contraint index in yaml doctrine 2"

Comment: The schema I posted accurately describes how to add an index for two foreign keys, with comments. You copied and pasted a schema that is incorrect for the question, and you took it straight from my Gist.

Comment: I don't want to boost any flame-war, but, @"Pete Michell", you have to have in mind that the stack overflow community is rather clear on that if you have a "content" to show, the content must be "in" the answer not just "linked". Always think that the coder needs to "see" the answer without getting away from S.O - Btw, the content you placed "in" the answer is "different" from the one in the link. The gist mentions the `indexes` key whilst in the "body" of your answer the word does not appear. In my personal case the `indexes` solved my issue. I don't feel @perrohunter "copied your answer".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for https://gist.github.com/1845982

```
Vendor\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogImage:
    type: entity
    table: blog_image

    # use two fields for our identifier
    id:
        blog:
            # flag as an association key 
            associationKey: true
        image:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        caption:
            type: string

    # Specify our relationships for above
    manyToOne:
        project:
            targetEntity: Vendor\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog
            inversedBy: images

    oneToOne:
        image:
            targetEntity: Vendor\ImageBundle\Entity\Image
```